# Assign one object properties from another

Tags: php, laravel

How can I give a object a new property using a variable as the new property?

The following gives me the property object required:

```
switch ($property['property_type']):
    case 'Residential':
        $property = $this->property
                         ->join('residential', 'property.id', '=','residential.property_id')
                         ->join('vetting', 'property.id', '=', 'vetting.property_id')
                         ->where('property.id', $id)
                         ->first();

        $property['id'] = $id;
        break;
    default:
        return Redirect::route('property.index');
        break;
endswitch;
```

The following gives me a list of attributes and values:

```
$numeric_features = App::make('AttributesController')->getAttributesByType(2);
```

Here is the problem, how do I dynamically add the each of `$numeric_features` to the property object?

```
foreach ($numeric_features as $numeric_feature) {
    ***$this->property->{{$numeric_feature->name}}***=$numeric_feature->value;
}
```

Comment: `$property['id'] = $id;` is this an array? and how about the `$numeric_features` how is it organized? key-value object? array?

Comment: @Webinan No they are both objects, they have both the result of a eloquent db query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

```
$property_names = array_keys(get_object_vars($numeric_features));

foreach ($property_names as $property_name) {
   $property->{$property_name} = $numeric_features->{$property_name};
}
```

and check this eval result, it adds one object's properties to another object: 
https://eval.in/517743

```
$numeric_features = new StdClass;
$numeric_features->a = 11;
$numeric_features->b = 12;

$property = new StdClass;
$property->c = 13;

$property_names = array_keys(get_object_vars($numeric_features));

foreach ($property_names as $property_name) {
   $property->{$property_name} = $numeric_features->{$property_name};
}
var_dump($property);
```

result:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
  ["c"]=>
  int(13)
  ["a"]=>
  int(11)
  ["b"]=>
  int(12)
}
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for.